# How to delete triggers for lambda function from SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which is triggered by an Eventbridge rule. When I delete that Eventbridge rule, the trigger still appears in the lambda console.
[screenshot of lambda console, under configuration tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzURu.png)

Is there any api or sdk method like `deleteTrigger` or something?

However aws internally call this post method `https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/services/ajax?operation=deleteRelation&locale=en`

Comment: Its console glitch. Did you try refreshing console?

Comment: Yes, I tried refreshing the console, Its still there.